# How to compose a connection string without login credentials .net MySqlConnector/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql?

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework-core, unix-socket, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am looking for solution to use connection string without user name and password specified with MariaDB server. I am running app and DB server on same machine so I decided to use unix_socket authentication.

#### Steps to reproduce

I have two connection strings where neither variant has a password property specified:

**a)**

```cs
string cnn_str = @" 
Server=/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock;
Port=3306;
Database=mwsdb;
Protocol=unix;
AllowUserVariables=true;
UseAffectedRows=false;";
```

**b)** variant is the same as the first one, only extended with the `uid` property (inpired by exception)

```cs
// appends user name - user that runs the application
// in my case the user name is 'pi'
cnn_str += $"Uid={Environment.UserName};";
```

**Code to connect to the database**:

**1)** Only `MySqlConnector`

```cs
var connection = new MySqlConnection(cnn_str);
using (connection)
{
    connection.Open();
}
```

**2)** The way how I configure db context service in `Program.cs` using `Pomelo.EF` and `.UseMySql()`

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MwsDbContext>(dbContextOptions => dbContextOptions
/* either 2.1) */     .UseMySql(cnn_str, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(cnn_str))
/* or 2.2) */       // .UseMySql(new MySqlConnection(cnn_str), ServerVersion.AutoDetect(cnn_str))
);
```

#### The issue

I used simple code (console app) to test conectivity to MariaDB and put results into table.

| Code | Connection string | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a) | exception |
| 1 | b) | works |
| 2.1 | a) | exception |
| 2.1 | b) | works |
| 2.2 | a) | exception |
| 2.2 | b) | works |

The exeption which is thrown is always the same and says:

```cs
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user ''@'localhost'
 ...full exception output below...
```

I can see some information:

- Access is denied because of missing user name.
- Exception is thrown by `MySqlConnector`.

**Questions**:

1. Am I able to compose a connection string without login credentials?
2. I would be glad if someone could explain to me what pros and potential cons has `MySqlConnection` instance over connection string when passing as argument to `.UseMySql(cnn_str vs. MySqlConnection)`.

I appreciate any help or explanation thanks in advance.

#### Further technical details

HW: RaspberryPi 4 Model B

SW:

- OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye).

  - Local OS account: pi
- SQL: Mariadb 10.5.12 with enabled plugin unix_socket authentication.
- AppServer: nginx/1.18.0

**Application: .NET 6 WEB API and ConsoleApp (both tested) with packages:**

```xml
<PackageReference Include="MySqlConnector" Version="2.1.8" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="6.0.1" />
```

Other details about my project setup:

**Create system local user account**

- no home dir
- no-login
- no pw

```sh
sudo useradd -r pi
```

**MariaDB**

Socket file path:

```sh
root@rpi:~# ls /run/mysqld
mysqld.pid  mysqld.sock
```

Mariadb config file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` contains:

```sh
[client-server]
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

SQL select to locate file path:

```sql
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'socket';
+---------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                   |
+---------------+-------------------------+
| socket        | /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock |
+---------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec)
```

**SQL commands to create user and grant privileges to system user in MariaDB server database**:

```sql
CREATE USER 'pi'@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mwsdb.* TO 'pi'@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket;
```

---

**Exception**

```cs
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user ''@'localhost'
at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken canc>
at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, String logMessage, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src>
at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/Co>
at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/Co>
at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, Int32 startTickCount, Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection>
at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 406
at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.Open() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 369
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion.AutoDetect(String connectionString)
at Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Main>$>b__3(DbContextOptionsBuilder dbContextOptions) in /home/Prog>
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<AddDbContext>b__0(IServiceProvider p, DbContextOptionsBuilder b)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateDbContextOptions[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<AddCoreServices>b__0(IServiceProvider p)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEng>
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEng>
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /home/Program.cs:line 72
```

**Program.cs:line 72**

Apply migrations.

```cs
l. 72:    using MwsDbContext? context = app.Services.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService<MwsDbContext>();
l. 73:    context?.Database.Migrate();
```

Comment: Shouldn't the socket file be `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`?

Comment: Based on [Authentication Plugin - Unix Socket](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/) it states "The `unix_socket` authentication plugin works by calling the [getsockopt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) system call with the `SO_PEERCRED` socket option, which allows it to retrieve the `uid` of the process that is connected to the socket. It is then able to get the user name associated with that uid".  What web server are you using (you mentioned it is a Web API project).

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your advice. I messed something up before. I ran the tests again and put the results into a table. It makes no difference which socket file path is used `/var/run/mysqld` or `/run/mysqld`, because `/var/run` refers to `/run`. It also makes no difference if I use `MySqlConnector` or `Pomelo` (with ConsoleApp or with WebAPI), both work or throw an exception with the same connection string. I changed the Issue and Questions sections in the description.

Comment: It sounds like you can get it working, but it needs the `uid` option which shouldn't be necessary.  I would open a new issue on the [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/) repo and link to it in your question.  If you can attach your sample ConsoleApp to the issue that would also help.  I think [OpenUnixSocketAsync](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/blob/e5cc8114730eaaa2c45921db688da3e17152c8ae/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs#L1139-L1186) may need updating to replace `UnixEndPoint` class with `UnixDomainSocketEndPoint`.

Comment: As the `pi` user, are you able to run `mysql mwsdb` and open a connection to the `mwsdb` database using Unix sockets without specifying a username on the command line?

Comment: Thanks you guys again for your answers... And Yes, I am able to run `mysql mwsdb` as `pi` without problem. `pi@raspberry:~ $ mysql mwsdb` then I am connected and database is used:
`MariaDB [mwsdb]>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I able to compose a connection string without login credentials?

No. MySqlConnector requires the UserID to be specified, even if using a Unix socket. This is covered in [this issue](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/1161).

The workaround is to set the username explicitly:

```cs
var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder("...connection string...");
builder.UserID = Environment.UserName;
using var connection = new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
```

(Or just hard-code `;Username = pi` in your connection string.)

> explain to me what pros and potential cons has `MySqlConnection` instance over connection string when passing as argument to `.UseMySql(cnn_str vs. MySqlConnection)`.

The two methods seem pretty equivalent: [connection string](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/blob/master/src/EFCore.MySql/Extensions/MySqlDbContextOptionsBuilderExtensions.cs#L92-L102) vs [connection](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/blob/master/src/EFCore.MySql/Extensions/MySqlDbContextOptionsBuilderExtensions.cs#L149-L161).

One uses the provided connection string; the other reads the `DbConnection.ConnectionString` property and uses that connection string. The former would be slightly more efficient because it's not creating an extra `MySqlConnection` object just to pass the connection string in; this is likely negligible in practice.

Comment: @tgo In addition to what Bradley already said in regards to your second question, the main reason to use a connection object over a connection string is to have control over the lifetime of the connection. If you pass an already opened connection to `UseMySql()`, the connection will not be closed/disposed once EF Core is done with it. Another reason is to run some custom statements before you want EF Core to take over (e.g. to set some session specific MySQL system variables or something similar). For the majority of people and use cases, just using a connection string is fine.